# How can i go back a level when specifying a path in C#?

Tags: c#, path, wix

I want to programmatically install a folder in Visual Studio's "Extensions" folder. The closest i can get is using the VS100COMNTOOLS environment variable. What i want to do is go back one level from the "Tools" folder, the go into IDE/Extensions, something like VS100COMNTOOLS..\IDE\Extensions. This is my code:

```
namespace TemplatesCustomAction
{
    public class CustomActions
    {
        [CustomAction]
        public static ActionResult CustomAction1(Session session)
        {

            var vspath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("VS100COMNTOOLS");

            session["VSINSTALLATIONFOLDER"] = string.Format(@"{0}\..\IDE\Extensions", vspath);



            return ActionResult.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That should work just fine. What problems are you seeing?

Comment: I get ".." invalid character in path. When i run my MSI

Comment: You could also do the "longer" way of creating a `DirectoryInfo` and fetch the parent directory: `new DirectoryInfo(vspath).Parent.FullName;`

Comment: Path.GetDirectory passed a directory will return the parent, and build Paths with Path.Combine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`Path.GetFullPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx):

```
var pathWithParent = string.Format(@"{0}\..\IDE\Extensions", vspath);
session["VSINSTALLATIONFOLDER"] = Path.GetFullPath(pathWithParent);
```

Though I'd also rather use `Path.Combine`:

```
var pathWithParent = Path.Combine(vspath, @"\..\IDE\Extensions");
```

Comment: Path.GetFullPath worked to give me the path after accounting for the "..\" (go up a directory) symbols in the path.  Path.Combine just combined the two strings, but did not account for and remove the "..\" symbols in the path.

Comment: "\" is for Windows, thats not crossplatform

Comment: @AlexanderDanilov - wix (which is tagged in the quesiton) is windows only.

Comment: @Oded yes but the question is about C# path, not about wix or anything else, and people who search for exactly that question (like me) will find it. And there won't be another same question because it will be marked as duplicate. So it should be correct in all senses. And also it would be better if the author removes all the code that doesn't refer to it.

Comment: @AlexanderDanilov - there is an edit link on the post. You are more than welcome to improve it.